# SPARQL filter by date for multiple predicates parameters with same subject

Tags: python, schema, sparql, rdf

I would like to select the car brands (filter contains prefix "dbr:") where schema:Motor and filter schema:dateManufactured > year 2000.

This is the source data (at the bottom you will find my query).

As per RedCrusaderJr answer, we got now the brands but I don't know how to specify the query to filter the date of manufacture and the schema:Motor.

```
cars = '''@prefix ex: <https://example.org/resource/> .
@prefix schema: <https://schema.org/> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> .
@prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

ex:Mustang ex:Deportivo dbr:Ford ;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina ;
    ex:potencia "450";
    ex:km "120000";
    schema:dateManufactured "2020-05-29"^^xsd:date ;
    schema:wasInCompetition dbr:LeMans;
    rdfs:label "Ford Mustang GT"@en .

ex:GT ex:Deportivo dbr:Ford ;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina ;
    ex:potencia "550";
    ex:km "25000";
    schema:dateManufactured "1968-04-29"^^xsd:date ;
    schema:wasInCompetition dbr:LeMans;
    rdfs:label "Ford GT"@en .

ex:Fiesta ex:Utilitario dbr:Ford ;
    schema:Motor ex:Diesel ;
    ex:potencia "100";
    ex:km "45000";
    schema:dateManufactured "2020-02-10"^^xsd:date ;
    rdfs:label "Ford Fiesta"@en .

ex:206 ex:Utilitario dbr:Peugeot ;
    schema:Motor ex:Diesel ;
    ex:potencia "68";
    ex:km "173100";
    schema:dateManufactured "2004-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
    rdfs:label "Peugeot 206"@en .
   
ex:California ex:Deportivo dbr:Ferrari;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina;
    ex:potencia "460";
    ex:km "500000";
    schema:dateManufactured "2010-05-29"^^xsd:date ;
    schema:wasInCompetition dbr:LeMans;
    rdfs:label "Ferrari California"@en .

ex:Enzo ex:Deportivo dbr:Ferrari;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina;
    ex:potencia "";
    ex:km "200000";
    schema:dateManufactured "2002-05-29"^^xsd:date ;
    schema:wasInCompetition dbr:LeMans;
    rdfs:label "Ferrari Enzo"@en .

'''


g_q1 = RDFGraph()
g_q1.parse (data=cars, format="turtle")

my initial query ='''
    SELECT ?h 

    {
      ?h schema:Motor ?t;
      :dateManufactured ?date.
      FILTER (?date > "2000-12-31"^^xsd:date)
    }
'''

RedCrusaderJr answer = SELECT * 
{
    {
        SELECT DISTINCT ?o
        { 
            ?s ?p ?o
            FILTER CONTAINS(str(?o), "http://dbpedia.org/resource/")
        }
    }

    #here I understand it would go the schema:motor and date manufactured part.
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: the property in your data is called `schema:dateManufactured` not `:dateManufactured`. You should also declare the prefixes in your SPARQL query to make it more self-contained and many parsers will even reject a query with unknow prefixes.

Comment: thanks UniformedUser! Last thing, I have seen that I was selecting the model "Enzo" instead of the brand "Ferrari" in the query.(to put an example). How could I select the dbr subject instead of the first ex? If you put it as answer I will accept it :) thanks!!!

ex:Enzo ex:Deportivo dbr:Ferrari;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina;
    ex:potencia "";
    ex:km "200000";
    schema:dateManufactured "2002-05-29"^^xsd:date ;
    schema:wasInCompetition dbr:LeMans;
    rdfs:label "Ferrari Enzo"@en .

Comment: if you want to get the `ex:Deportivo`, then you have to do `SELECT ?d 

    {
      ?h ex:Deportivo ?d ; schema:Motor ?t ;
      schema:dateManufactured ?date.
      FILTER (?date > "2000-12-31"^^xsd:date)
    }`

Comment: Well thanks but that was not really my question. I need to select Dbr: Ferrari. But, not just Ferrari, all the Dbr: availables . What I don't want is to explicitly put Ferrari or Peugeot, ford... I want to select that field whatever the value it is.

Comment: @Joseph since we got the answer to the original question, could you please update it and explain what you are trying to achieve in a clearer way. Are you now trying to select all the URIs with  `dbr:` prefix or you need something else?

Comment: @UniinformedUser I saw you answer many sparql questions, but I also noticed that you rarely use the actual `Answer` section, but rather the `comments` section. Why so?

Comment: @Joseph Expand the original question so that we see the exact query and the exact result you got when saying `I have seen that I was selecting the model "Enzo"`. Then show us the exact data you would want in your result when you say `instead of the brand "Ferrari"`.

Comment: If you want all the URIs that have a `Dbr:` prefix, and that's how I understand `I need to select Dbr: Ferrari. But, not just Ferrari, all the Dbr: availables .`, I'll put the answer for that below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the follow up on the original question, if I understand you correctly, you want all URIs with a specific prefix, which you'd get with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?o
{       
   ?s ?p ?o
   FILTER CONTAINS(str(?o), "http://dbpedia.org/resource/")
}
```

For your data set you'd get these URIs:

```
dbpedia:Ford
dbpedia:LeMans
dbpedia:Peugeot
dbpedia:Delorean_Motor_Company
dbpedia:Pontiac
dbpedia:Ferrari
```

And if you want to use those URIs further on, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
{
    {
        SELECT DISTINCT ?o
        { 
            ?s ?p ?o
            FILTER CONTAINS(str(?o), "http://dbpedia.org/resource/")
        }
    }

    #rest of the query where ?o can be used
}
```

---

- EDIT:

---

If I run this

```
SELECT ?car ?brand ?motor ?dateManufactured
{
   ?car ex:Deportivo ?brand;
         schema:Motor ?motor;
         schema:dateManufactured ?dateManufactured.
    FILTER (?dateManufactured > "2000-12-31"^^xsd:date)
}
```

I get these triples

```
car             brand             motor         dateManufactured
ex:Mustang      dbpedia:Ford      ex:Gasolina   "2020-05-29"
ex:California   dbpedia:Ferrari   ex:Gasolina   "2010-05-29"
ex:Enzo         dbpedia:Ferrari   ex:Gasolina   "2002-05-29"
```

Can you edit your answer again, so I can see exactly what result you want to get? If you want to merge brands with car/motor/dateManufactured, you don't have to get all brands first, but simply use the `ex:Deportivo` that connect them -> `?car ex:Deportivo ?brand.`

Comment: Hello RedCrusaderJr, thanks! I have updated my question with your answer since I tried to add my previous query for the schema:motor and schema:dateManufactured ?date.
      FILTER (?date > "2000-12-31"^^xsd:date) but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: I have to say that only for selecting the brands the query works! I only need to be able to merge both needs in the same query :)

Comment: @Joseph have you checked the update?